# Sql query with join on table with ID not match

Tags: sql, join

I have two tables.

```
Table 1
Id 
UpdateId
Name

Table 2
Table1ID
UpdateID
Address
```

Each time user update, system will `insert` record to `table1`. But for `table2`, system only `insert` record when there is `update` in address.

Sample data

```
Table 1
1,1,name1
1,2,name1
1,3,name1update
1,4,name1update
1,5,name1
1,6,name2
```

Table 2

```
1,1,address
1,4,addressupdate
```

I want to get the result as following

```
1,1,name1,address
1,2,name1,address
1,3,name1update,address
1,4,name1update,addressupdate
1,5,name1,addressupdate
1,6,name2,addressupdate
```

How to make use of join condition to achieve as above?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a correlated subquery.  Here is standard syntax, but it can be easily adapted to any database:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.addressid
        from table2 t2
        where t2.table1id = t1.id and
              t2.updateid <= t1.updateid
        order by t2.updateid desc
        fetch first 1 row only
       ) as addressid
from table1 t1;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use left join when you want to take all columns from left table t1 even though it doesn't match with the other table with column updateid on t2 table.

```
select t1.id,t1.updateid,t1.name,t2.address from table1 t1
left join table2 t2
on t2.updateid= t1.updateid
```

you can read more about joins [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)

Comment: Yes. But it will show as NULL for the address column. This is not the expected.